# How to fill an arraylist with varying numbers of editText objects at runtime?

Tags: java, android

This is my first time working with recyclerview, and the example code I am looking at from the android guide creates a static nested class Viewholder. First off, I'm not positive what the purpose of viewholder is. You can see how they do it here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

I am making a flashcard app that allows multiple definitions for each term (like a multidimensional flashcard). My app allows the user to add as many EditTexts as they want, so I think the best way to handle this is to make an arraylist of editTexts in viewholder. However, I cannot figure out how to fill the arraylist correctly. I receive the error message when I call new EditText.

EditText (android.content.Context) in EditText cannot be applied
to(com.example.flashcards.InputAdapter.InputViewHolder)

Also, I made the class nonstatic instead of static, since it has to access the instance of the adapter's arraylist to know how many EditTexts to make. I hope this does not cause any problems, as all the example code I've seen makes this class static.

public class InputAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
    private ArrayList allData;  //Data is a class I made that extends arraylist. It stores

```
public InputAdapter(ArrayList<Data> input){
    allData = input;
}

public class InputViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { 
    public ArrayList<EditText> inputs; 

    public InputViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        for (int i = 0; i < allData.get(0).size(); i++){
            inputs.add(new EditText(this));  //where I get the error message
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help. Extra appreciation to those who explain why they did what they did, and what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> First off, I'm not positive what the purpose of viewholder is.

`ViewHolder` exists to solve two problems:

1. Inflating a view is very slow
2. Calling `findViewById()` is a little slow

RecyclerView makes you implement `onCreateViewHolder()` separately from `onBindViewHolder()` so that it can decide when you actually need to inflate a new view, solving issue #1. Conventions for `ViewHolder` say that you should call `findViewById()` only in the ViewHolder's constructor (and then access your views via `holder.myView` later on), solving issue #2.

> I receive the error message when I call new EditText.
>
> ```
> EditText (android.content.Context) in EditText cannot be applied to(com.example.flashcards.InputAdapter.InputViewHolder)
> ```

Examples will often show e.g. `new EditText(this)`, but that only works because the code is running inside of an `Activity`. All Activities are `Context`s, and the constructor needs a `Context`.

Inside a ViewHolder, you can get a `Context` from the `itemView`. So write this instead:

```
new EditText(itemView.getContext())
```

> Also, I made the class nonstatic instead of static, since it has to access the instance of the adapter's arraylist to know how many EditTexts to make. I hope this does not cause any problems

There is no requirement that `ViewHolder` classes be static. It is generally recommended that they be static in order to avoid possible performance problems (memory leaks etc), but if it works for you then there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: Note also that you probably don't want to compute the number of `EditText`s to display inside your ViewHolder's constructor, because ViewHolders can be re-used and re-bound to any position in your adapter. Instead, you should do this work inside `onBindViewHolder()` (and remember to remove the old views before creating a bunch of new edit texts).

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once. Thank you so much! This really clarifies the concept

Comment: No problem. I know that you're new to the site, so you don't have full privileges yet, but if this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it (and/or upvoting it, once you have 15 rep) as a hint to other users who might find this question. Comments are temporary in nature, and can be removed at any time.